# Command pattern vs Event syntax in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, command

I have recently read about the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)

This pattern is used to **"represent and encapsulate all the information needed to call a method at a later time."**

What is the difference between "creating an object that encapsulates method call + target object details" from a C# delegate? aren't these both offer the same (or very similar) functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very similar, but i think its the inverse.

A command is where something else calls on to a target delegate or object. An event is a broadcast to *n*-number subscribers.

Another difference is that the owner of the event doesn't have to know about all the different subscribers.

WPF both has commands and events. Say you have a button. You could subscribe to the `Click` event or you could have a `Command` in your view model that would get invoked when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 3):

Events in C# are actually an implementation of the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

The difference between an observer and a command is primarily the problems they are trying to solve.  In a command pattern, the purpose is to separate the decision to perform an action from executing it.  The point of the observer pattern is to notify interested parties of some occurrence without having to know the type and number of observers, or perhaps even if they exist at all.

That said, the delegates put on the event handler are Commands.  But, this is an implementation detail, not the point of the event.  If you read the observer article,

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the C# feature that most closely resemble this pattern is **delegates**, not events...

And yes, it's quite similar, but the Command pattern enables more complex scenarios (e.g. implementation of undo/redo)

Comment: Yes, i actually meant delegates, although events are simply an exposure level that is set on delegates.

Comment: @liortal, not really... events are actually pairs of methods (add/remove), similar to properties. See [this article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) for details

Comment: Yes, but i meant that they serve as an additional safety measure against deleting (nullifying) the delegate invocation list.